# How much attack power does the Master Sword have?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In Breath of the Wild the Master Sword had a base damage of 30. However, in Tears of the Kingdom the Master Sword doesn't have a listed attack power.

How much attack power does the Master Sword have in Tears of the Kingdom?

[image: Master sword]

Comment: I've improved my answer with more details about its glowing state

Answer (score 6):

Just like Breath of the Wild, the Master Sword in Tears of the Kingdom deals a base attack damage of 30.

This is confirmed by [Zelda wiki](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Master_Sword#Tears_of_the_Kingdom) and other sources [[1]](https://www.howtogame.net/guides/how-much-damage-does-the-master-sword-do-totk/), [[2]](https://screenrant.com/zelda-tears-kingdom-master-sword-how-much-damage/), [[3]](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-master-sword-damage-best-fuse-items-in-totk).

**EDIT:**

However, in the presence of every gloom-based enemy (meaning pretty much everything in the Depths or [Gloom Spawn](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Gloom_Spawn) on the surface) the sword starts glowing and its base power increases to 45.
It's important to note that this 1.5 multiplier only applies to the Master Sword base power. This multiplier has no effect on the fused material.

[image]

Source, [Austin John Plays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWUChMbHuBA).

Comment: Which I just realized you can increase by fusing things to the master sword. Nifty!

Comment: Zelda Wiki doesn’t cite a source or provide evidence, so citing them is also not citing a source or providing evidence.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike Zelda wiki is commonly accepted as a valid source, since it's maintained by a community. There's no need to prove their statements. Also because I found many Reddits giving the same information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146607/discussion-between-thomas-markov-is-on-strike-and-pinckerman).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the sword's base damage (cited as 30 in another answer), it is also appears that the Master Sword awakens in the presence of evil and does additional damage, similarly to the previous game.

In Breath of the Wild, the Master Sword would glow in the presence of guardian enemies that were corrupted by Calamity Ganon's influence and the attack power and durability of the sword would increase. Additionally the Sword's strikes would make a unique clanging sound.

In Tears of the Kingdom there was an instance where I was fighting an enemy and the Master Sword both started glowing and made that special clanging sound.

The enemy I was fighting was:

> Phantom Ganon

It also seems like the Master Sword did more damage. I suspect that the previous mechanics for the Master Sword also applied, but I can't say for certain without either doing some more rigourous testing, or citing a source which has. I'd love to know the exact mechanics.

Comment: A bit more succinctly, the Master Sword responded to malice in BOTW and similarly responds to gloom in TOTK. This encapsulated all scenarios (everyone affected by malice/gloom takes the extra damage)